# Why didn't my OrderBy bug give a compiler warning?

Tags: c#, linq

I had this code to sort my Array, and I just realized sorting wasn't working:

```
if(desc)items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ExpirationDate);
else items.OrderBy(x=>x.ExpirationDate);
```

Correct code is:

```
if(desc)items=items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ExpirationDate).ToArray();
else items=items.OrderBy(x=>x.ExpirationDate).ToArray();
```

But why did the compiler (I'm using both Mono and Visual C# 2010) not give me an error, or even a warning?
Am I missing some setting, or is it simply impossible for a C# compiler to realize my original code was useless? If the latter, are there any lint tools that will look for specific mistakes like this, that I could add to my compiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because its not an error, The compiler wont care if you dont use the returned value.

If you want additional warnings to tell you about things like this have a look at [JetBrains - ReShaper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 7):

It is perfectly valid to call functions and ignore results. Compiler does not know if particular function is pure or have side effect.

I don't think there is error/warning in such case.

Sample of function call that commonly called with ignoring result: [Dictionary.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx) - it actually returns `true`/`false` unlike pretty much all other `Dictionary`/`List` functions.